# test is failing to locate element and giving error "no such element: Unable to locate element"

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to locate an element but it is giving me

> "no such element: Unable to locate element".

My element is below link:

```
<a href="/Admin/Company/View?id=225896">View</a>

Xpath=//a[@href='/Admin/Company/View?id=225896']

Xpath=//*[contains(@href,'/Admin/Company/View?id=225896')]

Xpath=//*[contains(@href,'View?id=225896')]
```

and many more. How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

use this.

```
//*[local-name()='a'][@href='/Admin/Company/View?id=225896']
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the element is not in an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) otherwise you will have to switch to it before locating
2. Make sure that the element is not in the [Shadow Dom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) otherwise you will have to locate the relevant [ShadowRoot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot) object first and then use relative locators from the ShadowRoot
3. Make sure that the element is present in the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) by the time you're trying to find it, i.e. execute [getPageSource()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getPageSource--) function and ensure that it's there as it might be the case you will need to go for [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) if the element is added to the DOM via i.e. [AJAX call](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)
4. And last but not the least, try locating the element by [link text](https://www.guru99.com/locate-by-link-text-partial-link-text.html) using `View` as the criteria

   ```
   driver.findElement(By.linkText("View"))
   ```

Comment: As there are alot of View element for example if id is 123 or 321 or 231. All have LinkText as View. But i will definitely try 1st 3 thanks